# If $A$ and $B$ are nxn matrices such that $BA =I$ , does it follow that $AB=BA$? If so,explain.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My approach,

$A$ AND $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices such that,

$BA=I$

Now,

We can write, $A = AI$

$A= A (BA)$

$A= (AB)A$

$A(I-AB)=0$

$I-AB =0$

Hence, $AB=I$

I don't feel like what I'm doing is the correct way to go. Please help ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: $A=(AB)A \stackrel?\implies A(I-AB)=0$ and $AC=0  \stackrel?\implies C=0$

Comment: you need to justify going from A(I-AB)=0 to I-AB=0

Comment: The statement isn't true for linear transformations on infinite-dimensional vector spaces, so you must some use the fact that the matrices are $n\times n$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $AB = I$ then $BA = I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i) If you need feedback on your attempt, then that is provided by the first two comments.

Comment: Your third step is wrong. You go from $A-ABA=0$ to $A(I-AB)=0$. But if you multiply that out, you get $A-AAB$, not $A-ABA$. The correct expression you can get is $(I-AB)A=0$ (by factoring $A$ on the right), but then you cannot left-multiply by $B$ to conclude that $I-AB=0$, so you get stuck.